# Notepad++ all instances of character under a condition

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

This is my text

```
BROKEN This is a "sentence".
This sentence is an actual normal sentence.
```

I wish to replace/filter the quotation marks out of every line that has the word BROKEN in it
I thought this would be simple but I couldn't do it
my regex

```
(?=BROKEN)"
```

could I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also want to match double quotes before the word `BROKEN`, you can skip the whole line that does not contain the word.

Find what:

```
^(?!.*\bBROKEN\b).*\R?(*SKIP)(*F)|"
```

Replace with: (leave empty)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\bBROKEN\b)` Negative lookahead, assert that the word `BROKEN` does not occur
- `.*\R?(*SKIP)(*F)` Match the whole line including an optional newline and skip the match
- `|` Or
- `"` Match a double quote

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/rUI3k3/1).

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^.*?\bBROKEN\b|\G(?!^))[^"\r\n]*\K"`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
  ^               # beginning of line
    .*?             # 0 or more any character but newline
    \bBROKEN\b      # literally
  |               # OR
    \G              # restart from last match position
    (?!^)           # not at the beginning of line
)               # end group
[^"\r\n]*       # 0 or more any character that is not a quote or linebreak
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
"               # quote
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]